# Accessing external JSON file properties within script

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have scoured the internet in an attempt to solve this before posting my question. I am already utilising jQuery, so if solution requires jQuery this is fine.

Below is the first small snippet of my external JSON. Here is the directory path to said JSON: `/data/quiz.json`

```
[{
  "doc" : [{
    "name": "Q1",
    "question" : "Why?",
    "choice" : [{
      "value" : "A1",
      "answer" : "True"
    },
    {
      "value" : "A2",
      "answer" : "False"
    }]
  }]
}]
```

I have appropriately linked to this script in my html file (above my `app.js` file).

The first property—"`doc`"—is variable, it is stored in a variable called "`id`".

Why would the following code not be logging "Q1"?

```
var data = $.getJSON("/data/quiz.json"),
    test = data[id][0].name;
console.log(test); // TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Comment: It's an array, you need to call like this  test = data[0][id][0].name;

Comment: Make sure to declare test only after data has retrieved a value.

Comment: Can you show the value of `data`?

Comment: @swarooppallapothu this logged `// TypeError: Cannot read property 'doc' of undefined`. @JohnR `data` is where I am assuming my json is stored based on my init `data` declaration in the example. @AnthonyMcGrath I am of the understanding that I have declared `test` after `data` has been retrieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below snippet

```
$.getJSON( "/data/quiz.json", function( data) {
 var test = data[0][id][0].name;
 console.log(test); // 
});
```

Comment: This prints Q1. So can I assume that any functions I need to run should be wrapped in the `$.getJSON` block?

Comment: No, pass data as a input parameter for the functions that requires this data. Call those functions in the $.getJSON callback

Comment: Could you please link me to an example of this? I am not sure I understand.

Comment: `$.getJSON( "/data/quiz.json", function( data) {
doSomething(data);
});

function doSomething(data) {
 var test = data[0][id][0].name;
 console.log(test);
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try below one:

```
var test1 = data[0].doc[0].name;
console.log(test1);
```

Comment: I don't think that this is too different from @swarooppallapothu comment. Neither have resolved the issue. Still logging "TypeError: Cannot read property 'doc' of undefined"

Comment: Please log the variable "data" after receiving from JSON url to ensure the correct data received.

Answer (score 0):

From given details, its clear that **data** variable gets initialized with an array with single object.

To access the property **name**.

you can user any of the following.

```
var method1 = data[0]["doc"][0].name;
// OR
var method2 = data[0].doc[0].name;
// both prints "Q1" if console logged.
```

if you used a separate variable **id**  to store value **"doc"**
you can you method in the following way

```
var id = "doc";
var method1 = data[0][id][0].name;
```

This one works! Check out!

Comment: This doesn't resolve my issue. I am still getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'doc' of undefined" when I remove the `console.log`. Have I not called my JSON correctly?

Comment: console.log(data);

and add the result to this that helps to easier to fix the bug.